# How to i handle a bufferoverflowexception that pops out after using a custom AutoML model?

Tags: android, android-studio, automl, google-cloud-automl

**I am on a tutorial about deploying custom Models on AutoML onto edge, in this case an android device.**

link is here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tflite-android-tutorial

I followed the step to "customize" it with my own model and run, but i end up with a lot of buffoverflowexceptions.

**What I did:**

I exported my autoML models and i downloaded (out of the 3: metadata,.txt,.tflite) the .txt and the .tflite.

I followed up renaming them "graph.lite" and "labels.txt" like in the example and replaced the tutorial's example with mine on android studios. I also followed the tutorial's changes for custom models, like changing to byte etc.

**However, running the app crashes the app straight away. with the following error:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLeSy.png

I was hoping for an app that could detect chairs and tables!

Help is greatly appreciated!